# WSDL type "soapenc:string" cannot be resolved

Tags: soap, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws, rad

importing my WSDL into RAD 8 (websphere 6.1) gives error:

```
<wsdl:part name="muid" type="soapenc:string"/>
```

The string type that is references by muid cannot be resolved.

XSD: Type reference 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/#string' is unresolved

Comment: Relevant posts: [Cannot resolve the name 'soapenc:Array'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455218) and [JAX-WS client generation fails for Amazon WSDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455218/wsimport-cannot-resolve-the-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is a type which has been defined in "the" XML Schema. Check, which prefix is used to reference the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` (the XML Schema-namespace) in your WSDL (most probably something similar to `xsi`, `xs`, `xsd`).

Then change the line to

```
<wsdl:part name="muid" type="xs:string"/>
```

where `xs` is your namespace prefix.

Comment: `string` is also defined in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/` namespace, based on the XSD located at that address. `soapenc:string` appears to be an extension of `xs:string` (adding additional attributes), so switching the type is going to restrict the content allowed in this `wsdl:part`.