# SAXParseException cannot resolve SOAP-ENC:Array to a type definition component

Tags: validation, wsdl, xsd

I am trying to validate a SOAP response message against the WSDL and I'm following the sample given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979044/validating-soap-message-against-wsdl-with-multiple-xsds).  However, I get the exception below.

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'SOAP-ENC:Array' to a(n) 'type definition' component.`

I've seen [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455218/wsimport-cannot-resolve-the-name) about a similar error but I'm not sure if this is the same issue.  I also don't understand why `SOAP-ENC:Array` is considered non-standard in that question when it appears in the [SOAP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap11/#_Toc478383522).

Here is my validation code.  The exception is raised on the `Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemas)` line.

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document wsdlDoc = db.newDocument();
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
Source wsdlSource = new StreamSource(new File("d:\\temp\\demo.wsdl"));
transformer.transform(wsdlSource, new DOMResult(wsdlDoc));

NodeList schemaNodes = wsdlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI, "schema");
int nrSchemas = schemaNodes.getLength();

Source[] schemas = new Source[nrSchemas];
for (int i = 0; i < nrSchemas; ++i)
{
  schemas[i] = new DOMSource(schemaNodes.item(i));
}

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemas);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
Source soapMessage = new StreamSource(new File("d:\\temp\\soapmessage.xml"));
Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
validator.validate(soapMessage, result);
```

I've trimmed the WSDL and only left the relevant parts, or at least what I think is relevant.  If more is needed, I'll update the question.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
             xmlns:tns="run:demo" 
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             targetNamespace="run:demo">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="run:demo">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="itemsCT">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="Address" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="itemsArray">
        <xsd:complexContent>
          <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" 
                           wsdl:arrayType="tns:itemsCT[]"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the schema validator being called is not loading any schema document for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ -- either because it's a generic validator and doesn't have any inbuilt knowledge of SOAP namespaces, or because it did not manage to retrieve the schema document from the server at schemas.xmlsoap.org.

If you have a local copy of the schemas for the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ and http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ namespaces, you might try adding schema location information to the two xsd:import elements in your schema.  If you don't have a local copy, then I hope you have better luck getting responses out of schemas.xmlsoap.org than I did just now.